# Does there exist an uncountable set of non-overlapping open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

> Let $\mathcal S$ be a set of open intervals ($(a,b)$ where $a<b$, $a$, $b\in\Bbb R$) such that $I_1\cap I_2=\emptyset$ for all $I_1$, $I_2\in\mathcal S$ ($I_1\ne I_2$). Can $\mathcal S$ be uncountable?

I guessed the answer is yes because $\Bbb R$ is uncountable.

So we need a construction for $\mathcal S$ such that there exists a bijection $f:\mathcal S\to\Bbb R$.

I'm afraid I have no idea starting from here...

Comment: Hint: Think about the rational numbers in each such interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every non-empty open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a rational number. We can pick some bijection $\nu : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$, and now define the following map:

$$I \mapsto \min \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \nu(n) \in I\} : \mathcal{S} \to \mathbb{N}$$

As we assume the intervals in $\mathcal{S}$ to be disjoint, it follows that the map above is injective. Therefore, $\mathcal{S}$ is countable.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your fast and delicate answer.

Comment: @youthdoo The answer Anro provided is "the" answer, but I would be remiss not to mention the following alternative which may come up elsewhere (perhaps in measure theory with different terminology): For each positive integer $n$, let $L_n$ denote the set of members $I$ of $\mathcal{S}$ such that the length of $I\cap [-n,n]$ is at least $1/n$. Then $|I_n|\leqslant 2n^2$, and $\cup_n L_n=\mathcal{S}$.